# Как вынести код скрипта в отдельный файл?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube

Есть зацикленное видео-заставка. Интересует вопрос: как в данном случае можно вынести код скрипта `js` в отдельный файл с расширением **.js** (в `html` оставив только подключение), чтобы функционал остался прежним? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/kf7hrLgn/2/)

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper #player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        playlist: 'VGz0eoTSNZ8',
        loop: 1,
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        autohide: 1,
        modestbranding: 1,
        vq: 'hd1080'
      },
      videoId: 'VGz0eoTSNZ8',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  // 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Скопировать всё содержимое внутри тега `<script>` и вставить его в .js-файл?

Comment: ну попробуйте прежде чем что-то заявлять - видео сразу исчезает с экрана при таком топорном подходе

Comment: добавил фидл - https://jsfiddle.net/kf7hrLgn/2/

Comment: _видео сразу исчезает с экрана при таком топорном подходе_ - на самом деле нет, просто очевидно ты не туда подключал свой новый файл

Comment: @Вася я много чего пробовал прежде чем что-то заявлять. Если вы не смогли корректно скопировать код в файл и подключить этот файл на странице - это не во мне проблема, и не повод тут хамить.

Comment: @Regent вы не упомянули, что нужно подключить библиотеку `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` а это ключевой момент, при простом переносе без ее подключения работать не будет, о чем я вам и сказал всего-навсего, хамить и в мыслях не было, если вы приняли это на свой счет - здесь я извинюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри `player.js`:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      playlist: 'VGz0eoTSNZ8',
      loop: 1,
      controls: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      autohide: 1,
      modestbranding: 1,
      vq: 'hd1080'
    },
    videoId: 'VGz0eoTSNZ8',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
}


function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute();
}
```

Внутри `<your_name>.html`:

```
<script src="path-to-js/player.js"></script>
```

Или:

```
<script src="/relative-url-to-assets/js/player.js"></script>
```

В зависимости от расположения файла и ситуации. Если у вас статические файлы находятся по какому-то `url`, то используйте второй вариант, слегка модифицировав. Если у вас файл хранится локально, то нужно использовать первый вариант, указав путь до файла относительно текущего расположения .html-файла (aka. `relative path`).

Comment: в рамках фидла это можете продемонстрировать? https://jsfiddle.net/kf7hrLgn/2/

Comment: @Вася, хорошо, подождите секундочку

Comment: @Вася https://jsfiddle.net/kf7hrLgn/4/

Comment: у меня к вам только вопрос - а зачем вы подключили player_api ?

Comment: @Вася, на самом деле все и так работает: https://jsfiddle.net/kf7hrLgn/5/

Comment: @Вася просто взял код из своего проекта с корректировками под ваш. На деле, действительно можно просто сделать, как тов. Grundy.